# TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory) OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to get my head around WCF transactions but struggling with one concept. What is the difference in behaviour of

```
TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)
```

and

```
OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)
```

As far as I can tell from the documentation they are kind of two ways of achieving the same thing, but I cannot really figure it out.

Cheers,

Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a transaction scope is required for a method, WCF will create a transaction to execute the method's logic.  Transaction flows allow you to chain transactions, so that multiple service methods that require transactions can all be joined into a single transaction instead of separate transactions.

Consider the following simple setup:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]   
public void ServiceMethod1()
{
    // Executes ServiceMethod2 and ServiceMethod3
}

[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]    
public void ServiceMethod2()


[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]    
public void ServiceMethod3()
```

ServiceMethod1 requires a transaction, so WCF spins up a transaction and then calls ServiceMethod2 and ServiceMethod3.  Although these services also require a transaction, they are flowed.  So instead of spinning up new transactions, they adopt the same transaction that was created by ServiceMethod1.  If anything fails along the way or the transaction isn't committed, the entire chain gets rolled back.  If the transactions were not flowed, each method would spin up a transaction that acted on it's own and had no effect on other methods being called.

Comment: OK, so TransactionScopeRequired=true requires a transaction for the operation but TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory executes multiple operations to execute within the same transaction.

Comment: TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory will "flow", or continue under the identifier of the current transaction, from the calling function if such a transaction exists.  If there is not a pre-existing transaction, this directive will then cause WCF to spin up a new transaction.