# OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true) vs TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)

Tags: c#, wcf

I found one answer for this question here:

[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory) OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440494/transactionflowtransactionflowoption-mandatory-operationbehaviortransactionsc)

what I'm still missing here is, how those two, seperate configurations, will work together.

for example if I have this:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
```

and than this:

```
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowd)]
```

would transaction be mandatory/required or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If client has a transaction service will use it with TFO.Allowed only if binding is allowing it and client is propagating it in its binding as well.

TransactionSocepRequired = true and transaction is flowed from client, ambient transaction of the services will be set to the clients transaction.

The answer is: if client does not set transaction WCF will create a new transaction as the ambient transaction.

Here is the table with the combinations (credit Juval Lowy Programming WCF Services book) :

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+------------------+
| Binding transaction flow | TransactionFlowOption | TransactionScopeRequired | Transaction mode |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+------------------+
| False                    | Allowed               | False                    | None             |
| False                    | Allowed               | True                     | Service          |
| False                    | Not Allowed           | False                    | None             |
| False                    | Not Allowed           | True                     | Service          |
| True                     | Allowed               | False                    | None             |
| True                     | Allowed               | False                    | None             |
| True                     | Allowed               | True                     | Client/Service   |
| True                     | Mandatory             | False                    | None             |
| Tru                      | Mandatory             | True                     | Client           |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Rows 5 and 6 are duplicates, i think you were trying to say at row 6 `TransactionScopeRequired` `True` instead of `False` :)